# Obtener todos los datos de una tabla html para procesarlos en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Tengo una página donde el usuario crea un pedido en una tabla html, mediante un botón agrega nuevas filas, al terminar preciona un boton de agregar al carrito, cuando esto sucede, necesito obtener todos los datos de esta tabla html para guardarlos en una clase o en base de datos para ir formando el carrito de compras.
Adjunto una imagen de cómo se ve [image: Así se ve el formulario descrito]

```
function validaPedido(route){
    // Obtengo el head dinamicamente
    var head = "";
    $('table #thead_mas_opciones tr:first th').each(function() {
      // Obtengo el valor de dicho th
      if($(this).text().trim() != "Eliminar Fila"){
          head += $(this).text().trim();
          head += "|";
      }
    });

    head = head.substring(0, head.length -1);

    console.log(head);

    console.log("-----------------------------");

    // Obtengo el body dinamicamente
    var body = "";
    
    $('table #tbody_mas_opciones tr td').each(function() {
      if($(this).children().get(0).nodeName == 'SELECT' || 
         $(this).children().get(0).nodeName == 'INPUT' || 
         $(this).children().get(0).nodeName == 'FILE'){
        body += $(this).children().val();
        body += "|";
      }

    });

    body = body.substring(0, body.length -1);

    console.log(body);
}
```

Adjunto la solución, puede no ser la más efectiva pero funciona, si conocen de alguna manera de mejorar el código les agradezco. Gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué parte del código tienes hecha?. Es importante que la pregunta se adapte a [ask], para que no sea reportada como de baja calidad, y termine como cerrada. También  puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y obtener tú primera medalla.

Comment: En el botón agregar nuevas filas supongo que agrega los campos que rellena el usuario. Esos campos supongo que son parte de un formulario.  El script solo tiene que leer los campos del formulario, por ejemplo con getElementsByTagName('input') tendrías todos los inputs o si en el pedido a los inputs les pusiste un name común o una clase o un data- pues usas este atributo. No pones nada de código ni sobre lo que has intentado, así no puedo ayudar más.

Comment: Te podemos ayudar si mostraras tu código.

Comment: Podrían reabrir mi pregunta por favor, realmente necesito una respuesta y no deseo crear una pregunta duplicada. Gracias

Comment: Votaré para reabrirla, pero coloca el código como texto por favor

Comment: Listo @Christian ya está el código en texto

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que no quieres tener que enviar el formulario constantemente ... en ese caso creo que te puede servir emplear una API Rest, por ejemplo con jQuery podrías hacerlo y en PHP sería algo así:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../../../db/MySQLdb.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    $bbdd = new MySQLdb(); // Inicializamos la clase de la BBDD
    

    //recuperamos los argumentos    
    $ciudad = $_GET['provincia'];
    $servicio = $_GET['categoria'];
    $pclave = $_GET['pclave'];
    
    $resultado = //consulta a la BBDD con SELECT ....
    print json_encode('no implementado');
    
} else {
    
    print json_encode('No autorizado');
    
}
```

AL llamar desde jQuery este devolvería ( si tiene sesión ) todos los datos , por ejemplo el resultado del select ...

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, aunque el problema no es consultar a base de datos, eso lo haría con lo que me dijiste y de esa manera llenaría la tabla html, aquí necesito el proceso contrario, tengo la tabla html llena de datos escritos por el usuario y necesito obtenerlos para guardarlos en la base de datos